# Escape Comma in Column While Creating CSV in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, csv

**I need to escape comma in Column values while Creating CSV file in LWC. I tried with replacing comma with Keywords but still when converting string into blob it splits value with comma. I'm sending JSON String from LWC which I need to convert in CSV.**

*.cls*

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static string saveTemplate(String jsonBody){
        try {
            string message = 'Subcontract Task Template Updated Successfully!';
            List<Object> dataList = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody);
            List<String> csvRowValues = new List<String>();
            for(Object obj : dataList){
                Map<String,Object> mpStrObj = (Map<string,Object>)obj;
                String category = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Category')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Category')) : '';
                String taskName = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('TaskName')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('TaskName')) : '';
                String assignedTo = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('AssignedTo')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('AssignedTo')) : '';
                String priority = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Priority')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Priority')) : '';
                String status = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Status')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Status')) : '';
                String dueDate = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('DueDate')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('DueDate')) : '';
                String startDate = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('StartDate')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('StartDate')) : '';
                String endDate = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('EndDate')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('EndDate')) : '';
                String description = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Description')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Description')) : '';
                String notes = String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Notes')) != null ? String.valueOf(mpStrObj.get('Notes')) : '';
                
                String rowStr = category + ',' + taskName + ',' + assignedTo + ',' + priority + ',' + status + ',' + dueDate + ',' + startDate + ',' + endDate + ',' + description.escapeCsv() + ',' +notes.escapeCsv();
                system.debug('Rowstr : '+rowStr);
                String temp = handleCommas(rowStr);
                csvRowValues.add(temp);
                
            }
            String csvColumnHeader = 'Category,Task Name,Assigned To,Priority,Status,Due Date,Start Date,End Date,Description,Notes\n';
            String csvFile = csvColumnHeader + String.join(csvRowValues,'\n');
            csvFile = csvFile.replaceAll(':quotes:', '').replaceAll(':comma:', ',');
            Blob body = blob.valueOf(csvFile);
            
            Document docId = [SELECT Id FROM Document WHERE Name = 'Subcontract Task Template'];
            
            document doc=new document();
            doc.Body= body;
            doc.Id = docId.Id;
            update doc;
            
            return message;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
   
 public static String handleCommas(String csvLine){
        
        String prevLine = csvLine;
        Integer startIndex;
        Integer endIndex;
        
        while(csvLine.indexOf('"') > -1){
            
            if(startIndex == null){
                startIndex = csvLine.indexOf('"');
                csvLine = csvLine.substring(0, startIndex) + ':quotes:' + csvLine.substring(startIndex+1, csvLine.length());
            }else{
                if(endIndex == null){
                    endIndex = csvLine.indexOf('"');
                    csvLine = csvLine.substring(0, endIndex) + ':quotes:' + csvLine.substring(endIndex+1, csvLine.length());
                }
            }
            
            if(startIndex != null && endIndex != null){
                String sub = csvLine.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
                sub = sub.replaceAll(',', ':comma:');
                csvLine = csvLine.substring(0, startIndex) + sub + csvLine.substring(endIndex, csvLine.length());
                startIndex = null;
                endIndex = null;
            }
        }
                
        return csvLine;
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect the CSV file to be processed by that you want to use ":comma:" as an "escape"? Have you checked the [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) specification that covers how CSV files should be constructed, including how to escape commas (by wrapping the value in double quotes) and double quotes (by doubling up the quotes)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace the entire `handleCommas` function with the built-in `replaceAll` string function. This function takes a regex. In this case, it's looking for one or more commas.

Eg:

```
String str = 'what up, my homie, yall';
str = str.replaceAll(',+','comma');
System.debug(str);
//prints "what upcomma my homiecomma yall"
```